# Meizu MX4 Ubuntu edition not mounting as USB drive and not available to adb

Tags: usb, mount, ubuntu-touch, adb

My Meizu MX4 Ubuntu edition arrived this week and I'm figuring out how to use it.  One big problem is that I can't get USB access to copy data, either as a USB drive or using adb.  My computer is a MacBook running Yosemite, I also have a Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu Trusty.  When I plug the phone into the MacBook there's a bunch of stuff in the phone's dmesg:

```
[102352.913708] musb-hdrc musb-hdrc: <== Power=f1, DevCtl=99, int_usb=0x4
[102352.913731] musb-hdrc musb-hdrc: BUS RESET as b_peripheral
[102352.913784] [U3D][U2 RESET_INTR]
[102352.913791] [U3D]USB Speed = High Speed
[102353.215731] mtp_open
[102353.253474] mtp_release
[102353.253498] mtp_release, line 1846: _mtp_dev->dev_disconnected = 1
[102353.332582] mtp_open
[102353.356133] mtp_release
[102353.356156] mtp_release, line 1846: _mtp_dev->dev_disconnected = 1
[102353.432300] mtp_open
[102353.450624] mtp_release
[102353.450647] mtp_release, line 1846: _mtp_dev->dev_disconnected = 1
[102353.518418] mtp_open
[102353.540273] mtp_release
[102353.540295] mtp_release, line 1846: _mtp_dev->dev_disconnected = 1
[102353.602370] mtp_open
[102353.623471] mtp_release
[102353.623495] mtp_release, line 1846: _mtp_dev->dev_disconnected = 1
[102353.663670] android_usb gadget: high-speed config #1: android
[102353.663691] mtp_function_set_alt intf: 0 alt: 0
[102353.733945] mtp_open
```

But there's nothing at all in the MacBook's dmesg.  If I insert a normal USB stick the MacBook shows something like:

```
USBMSC Identifier (non-unique): C86000BDB9EACEB1BA2F8CAD 0x930 0x6544 0x100, 2
```

If I plug into the Raspberry Pi dmesg shows:

```
[ 8931.487843] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 10 using dwc_otg
[ 8931.577504] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=2a45, idProduct=0c02
[ 8931.577529] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[ 8931.577546] usb 1-1.3: Product: MX4_Ubuntu_Edition 
[ 8931.577561] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: meizu
[ 8931.577576] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 750ABLMPX44Y
```

I can then use lsusb to get more information:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 2a45:0c02  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

lsusb doesn't know who "2a45" is even though dmesg apparently does.  Following the suggestion of @Maarten Klop I added 0x2a45 to ~/.android/adb and adb now shows:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
????????????    no permissions
```

I can't put or get files and I can't get a shell because of a lack of permissions.

On the MacBook, if I use Android Device Monitor, I see a listing under Devices for "mx4_ubuntu_edition-750ABLMPX44Y".  But again I can't get access to any files, logs, or do anything useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Screen must be unlocked, I did not experience USB port issues. For me, this was the critical step:

The file *~/.android/adb_usb.ini* on your computer is a list of valid vendorIDs that are allowed to connect. I found that list empty (or non existent, don't remember). Just add a new line with the vendorID for the MX4, you found it already:

0x2a45

I also had to do this for Aquaris E4.5, then the ID is 0x2a47.

Good luck!

Comment: Adding the vendor ID helped!  Not to the point that it's usable ;-) but enough that I'm optimistic it'll work eventually.

Comment: Actually on the MacBook it turns out to be perfectly usable on the command line.  adb shell, adb push, adb pull all working.  Android Device Monitor still doesn't work, and I can't get anything working on the Ubuntu Raspberry Pi.  Good enough though, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The MX4 USB port is picky and unstable with USB3.0. Please try to connect to USB2.0 port or USB2.0 hub to see if it fixed your issue.

Comment: @Tim: I voted "Looks OK"... :/

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem with my BQ and found out that it shows up as a drive only while the screen is unlocked.

If that doesn't work you might want to enable developer mode (System Settings -> About this phone -> Developer Mode) before trying one more time with the unlocked screen.

Comment: All of my attempts were with the screen unlocked.  I also tried in Developer Mode and got the same result.  I also tried using adb with the phone in Developer Mode and that doesn't work at all.