# Ubuntu MX4 not detected on Ubuntu SDK

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, ubuntu-sdk, adb, meizu-mx4

Just got hold of the Meizu MX4 which comes pre-installed with Ubuntu Touch. I have been using the Ubuntu SDK for some time now, today I tried to deploy a simple app onto the device.

However, several of my computers (all running Ubuntu 14.04) are unable to connect to the phone. What I mean by this is, when I connect the phone to the desktop via USB, Ubuntu SDK will not list the device in the devices tab. Things I have tried:

- 'adb devices' will show no listed devices (I have tried different USB ports on different computers, and the daemon is running on the phone)
- I have managed to log in via SSH. The SDK has a feature to test the SSH connection and list processes, so this works. I have also transferred my own (non-QT) public key to SSH from the terminal.
- Developer mode is definitely on

[My problem is exactly the one as described here](https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-phone@lists.launchpad.net/msg13640.html).

[This person also made a more thorough investigation about this issue on askubuntu, but seems to have no solutions which work.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/632444/meizu-mx4-ubuntu-edition-not-mounting-as-usb-drive)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meizu MX4 Ubuntu edition not mounting as USB drive](http://askubuntu.com/questions/632444/meizu-mx4-ubuntu-edition-not-mounting-as-usb-drive)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by @Maarten Klop, adding the vendor ID to adb_usb.ini seems to help:

```
mat@ACA80164:~$ cat .android/adb_usb.ini
# ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.
# USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.
# 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE.
0x2a45
```

After doing that:

```
mat@ACA80164:~$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
750ABLMPX44Y    device

mat@ACA80164:~$ adb shell
phablet@ubuntu-phablet:~$ ls
Documents  Downloads  Music  Pictures  Videos
```

This works on my MacBook, but it isn't working nearly as well for me on my Ubuntu Raspberry Pi.

Comment: This works for me too. Note to anyone else that there was no adb_usb.ini file but creating one did solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to add the vendor USB ID:

```
vi ~/.android/adb_usb.ini
0x2a45
```

I also needed to:

```
vi /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2a45", MODE="0664" GROUP="plugdev"

udevadm control --reload
udevadm trigger
```

I restarted the adb server and it worked.